# Codeigniter updating database with checkbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

i have a table named group where i have columns like admin,editor,user,guest they are all boolean.  
i want to create a group using checkbox. so in my view i got checkbox like admin,editor,user,guest and a create button. When i click the create button i want the checked options to be true in database and unchecked remains false. how can i do that?

I am new in codeigniter.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create A group</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo form_open('group/create_group'); ?>
    <div>
        <?php echo form_label("Gruop Name"); ?> 
        <?php 
        $data=array(
        'name'=>'group_name',
        'placeholder'=>'enter group name'
        );
     ?>
         <?php echo form_input($data); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php $data=array(
        'name'=>'role[]',
        'value'=>'1',
        'type'=>'checkbox'
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_label('Admin'); ?>
        <?php echo form_checkbox($data); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php $data=array(
        'name'=>'role[]',
        'value'=>'2'
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_label('User'); ?>
        <?php echo form_checkbox($data); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php $data=array(
        'name'=>'role[]',
        'value'=>'3'
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_label('Editor'); ?>
        <?php echo form_checkbox($data); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php $data=array(
        'name'=>'role[]',
        'value'=>'4'
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo form_label('Others'); ?>
        <?php echo form_checkbox($data); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php $data=array(
        'type'=>'submit',
        'value'=>'Create'
        ); ?>
        <?php echo form_submit($data); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you share tried code ?

Comment: i haven't tried the model code not sure where to start from

Comment: refer the link for how to use model  in codeigniter https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

Set "false" as default value at all those fields.

**Second**

If you can set only one role per user then you should use radiobox instead checkbox

**Third**

Capture the parameters sent by the post.

Assuming that you created a route for `group/create_group` that goes to the `data_submitted` method

```
public function data_submitted() {
    $data = array(
    'role' => $this->input->post('role'),
    //more info that you get from the post..
    );
    Now load your model and save it...
```

}

Comment: thnx for that...i get it :)

Answer (score 0):

Put off [] and in your php file logic your can do : `$this->input->post("role");` and get value. If you want to do multi-choice's checkbox your must change to an unique name and set value to true for each of them.

Have nice day !